# Android & Unity3D - Mix data exchange/action/communication and use UNity3D as an integration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am coming today because I would like to dev a small application using Unity3D and Android. The main idea is:

My app would be like a map with a couple of characters that can chat, so Unity3D is what I need to realize the graphic part of my app.

However, I would like to use Unity3D just as an integration. I mean by that that Unity would only render de graphic part when my android app would manage all the exchanges between my app and the API, but also the storage of the data and differents other views (such as menu, settings, etc).

How could I achieve that properly?

Also, I was wondering, if I want to integrate 2 differents views (The map, and a dressing), would it be possible to communicate between android and my 2 Unity3D integration?

I hope I am clear, I feel like I am just a bit lost.

Thank for any help about my questions :)

Comment: What you wish to achieve is possible by utilizing solely unity or integrating 3d frameWorks like libGdx on android studio. Also possible to achieve by building two different programes that will talk via reading and writing data like txt files. You are talking about adding a unity program with other programs, I'm unsure if wrapping both such way is possible.

Comment: Interesting ! In fact I am trying to use mapbox (extrusion + 3d models) but I would like to use 3d cards for the gameplay. However, the rest of the app would be just a simple app, it's just there are 2 scene that would be animated designs :)

Comment: its going to be a hassle, why not make your app 100% unity3d?